# Eliminate brief flash in Chrome when using jQuery.show() to swap in an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

### Description of Problem:

Chrome seems to briefly display a flash (intermittently, but usually) when swapping objects via jQuery's `.show()`.

### Example:

[JSFiddle link.](http://jsfiddle.net/P7ap5/5/)

Code:

```
var $catGo = $('#cat_animate');
var $catStop = $('#cat_still');

$('#wrapper').on('click', '#cat_still', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $catGo.attr('src', 'http://i.imgur.com/kPUYc5y.gif');
    }, 0);
    $catGo.show();
    $catStop.hide();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $catGo.hide();
        $catStop.show();
        setTimeout(function() {
            $catGo.attr('src', '');
        }, 0);
    }, 11400);
});
```

### Additional Notes:

Click the cat in Chrome, and notice how when it swaps out the still image for the animated one, there's frequently a brief flash as it changes over to the animated image. This never occurs in Firefox or any other browser I've tried. Is there a way to eliminate it programmatically? Try your hand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

So firefox seems to cache images pretty good, you can go to that image directly and refresh and it will be on the same time. The code below seemed to work good for me in firefox and chrome though.

http://jsfiddle.net/YwVuV/

```
var $catGo = $('#cat');

$('#wrapper').on('click', '#cat', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $catGo.attr('src', 'http://i.imgur.com/kPUYc5y.gif');
}, 0);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $catGo.attr('src', 'http://i.imgur.com/64a9Ofb.jpg');
    }, 11400);
});
```

This updated Fiddle also assists with multiple clicks to the image by assigning the setTimeout to a variable and clearing it on click, so multiple src changes do not execute on multiple clicks.

http://jsfiddle.net/24sTS/

Hope this helps.

Comment: On first playthrough (of your second Fiddle; L6X2Q), it plays seamlessly. However, on subsequent playthroughs, the flash is still there. This is presumably because you're resetting the src after the initial click and doing so is causing the flicker.

Comment: I noticed it and edited it. it was due to the setTimeout setting the $catGo source to empty

Comment: Unfortunately (for me), your new Fiddle (CYGmM) reintroduces the problem of Firefox continually playing that image in the background, and so when you click it in Firefox, it does not start from the beginning and is not seamless. I cannot fault you for this as it's outside the scope of what I asked in the question, however. This is what I was struggling with, though: getting it to work seamlessly in both browsers. It requires a src reset for Firefox to loop it correctly, but then Chrome has a silly flashing problem. :-)

Comment: Alright, I got it working for you buddy. Should be OK. Tested it in chrome and firefox, no blink, no continuous image loop. Also added a second fiddle that will help with multiple clicks to the image before it completes animation.

Comment: For reasons I cannot fathom or explain, it still does not fully work in Firefox: occasionally, subsequent clicks do not register, and sometimes it will stop playing midway through for no reason whatsoever. I'm unable to faithfully replicate this behavior through testing; it seems utterly sporadic. My only theory is having both your Fiddles open simultaneously destroys Firefox's handling of gifs. Hopefully it's just something temporarily broken on my end and simply requires a browser restart to fix. Either way, it works flawlessly in Chrome now, and that's what my question was for, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest preloading the gif and only show your img after the image has loaded. e.g.

```
$('#wrapper').on('click', '#cat_still', function() {
    var i = new Image();
    $(i).load(function(){
        $cat_animated.attr('src', 'http://i.imgur.com/kPUYc5y.gif');
        $cat_animated.show();
        $cat_still.hide();
    });
    i.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/kPUYc5y.gif';
    // ... 
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this doesn't work in Firefox because the gif will continually play in the background and then when you show() it, it will not provide a seamless solution. That was the whole point of going through all the hooplah of setting and resetting the src when it's invoked.

Comment: just extended the example a litte bit - are you sure this causes problems in firefox? can't test it right now but i am pretty sure this should word as expected.

Comment: Positive, sir. If you'd like to see what Firefox does, visit the second Fiddle by @user2328185 above (http://jsfiddle.net/CYGmM/). It will loop continuously in the background so that when you invoke it, it starts in the middle of the gif rather than the beginning.

Comment: the fiddle really is unrelated to my suggestion ... i don't set the src until the click. preload happen with an image object that is never added to the page

Comment: doenst flicker here (osx) and starts at the beginning, but animation speed is terrible at best - i didn't realize ff has become such a diva, thnx for the info